# The [result] tag has been burninated

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

[result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/result) (900+) sounds not very useful. Shall we kill with fire?

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring: Q: +37/0, A1 (Saying Yes): +10/0

Comment: I don't know.  [I've worked in the private sector.  They expect *results*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4394VCS7POE).

Comment: For the record, it _could_ be useful as there is a `Result` type in some languages (Rust comes to mind). There don't exist tags for [rust-result] or [result-type], which would likely be better, though.

Comment: @jhpratt [result] is too ambiguous. If you feel like these tags should be created, create them! Don't forget to suggest a tag wiki edit with the usage, so that people know how to use it and it won't become ambiguous.

Comment: @jhpratt That information could probably go into the retagging observations answer if this burnination goes forward.

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring: Q: +88/-3, A1 (Saying Yes): +31/-2. A2 (Saying Yes): +38/-2. A3 (Saying Yes) +8/-1. The community has voted in favor of the burnination.

Answer (score 39):

I began writing this answer thinking of saving the tag, as "result" in the common usage means "output", but when I saw the tag itself and dug more into it, I agree with the burnination. The [result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/result) tag has multiple issues:

- It *is* ambiguous in the sense that the "result" which the post is talking about can either be a search result or a program result.
- It doesn't add anything meaningful to the question and is at most a dependent tag.
- Given its dependent nature, the tag by itself isn't on topic for the site, without the addition of another meaningful tag.
- There are no top users of the tag, the highest number of posts a single user has answered in that tag is 4.

All that said, a bit more digging reveals that more than 850 of the posts out of the 980 have answers, and just 20 of the posts are closed (non duplicate closure). There have been 90 posts that have been deleted, with around 70 of them being atleast 3 years old.

These facts show that the tag is being used in a non-harmful manner. I think this tag comes under the "pointless extra work" which Shog mentions in the original burnination criteria meta. So my idea would be to just look at the [66 negatively scored questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bresult%5D+score%3A..-1+hasaccepted%3A0++is%3Aq&mixed=0), close the ones that are needed, and just ask Shog to drop the guillotine on the tag.

Answer (score 32):

Seems like a good idea to me - as far as I can tell, it's used when a program/query/function has some form of output, which is almost always.

Answer (score 10):

Result always seemed like an unimportant tag, taking up space another more valuable/defining tag could be, most things do produce an output/result and even if they do/don't it is usually clear from the question itself whether or not there is an intended result.

Burn it, it is an unnecessary tag.

Comment: That's a good point, actually. Strictly speaking, aren't almost all questions posted ultimately about some kind of result (either about how to achieve a particular result, or about why their program is producing a result that the the OP doesn't like)?

Answer (score 8):

[result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/result) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- Use the [rust-result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-result) tag for the questions related to the Result keyword in the rust language.
- Use the [resultset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resultset) tag for questions related to the `resultSet` object.

## Progress:

The [result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/result) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=result),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bresult%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bresult%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bresult%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bresult%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## [Track the progress of the burnination!](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192617)

[Dashboard for progress](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=251011)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/result) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/result) tag — just flag/vote to close the question.

#### Do not downvote questions in order to trigger roomba

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/result) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: For questions that should be closed, do we remove the tag AND vtc? Or just vtc?

Comment: Just vtc, @KodosJohnson.